# How to bind and auto update listbox wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, binding, listbox

Ok here several questions

First

This is my implementation but it is not working atm how can i make it work ?

```
    <Grid> // xaml part
    <Button Content="Start Crawling Root Sites - This Deletes All Data" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="279" Command="{Binding StartCrawling}" Click="click_start_Crawling"  />
    <ListBox Name="lstBoxEvents" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Height="138" Margin="294,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="312">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="1">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding ocEvents}"  />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>


        private void click_start_Crawling(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) // inside mainwindow
    {
        PublicStaticFunctions.AddMsgToEvents("trial");
    }

    public static class PublicStaticFunctions // seperate class
{
    public static ObservableCollection<string> ocEvents = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public static void AddMsgToEvents(string srMessage)
    {
        ocEvents.Insert(0, srMessage);
    }
}
```

My second question when running multithreaded, if multiple threads access AddMsgToEvents function and adds variable, would listbox still auto refresh without any problem ?

Thank you very much

Comment: Whats the problem exactly? The ListBox needs to have a `ItemsSource`. As long as the source is an `ObservableCollection`, it should propagate changes to the UI on add/remove.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange still not working http://fc03.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2014/223/5/5/notworkign_by_monstermmorpg-d7ur63s.png not updating

Comment: `ItemSource={binding ocEvents}`

Comment: @PoweredByOrange not working either

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
public static ObservableCollection<string> ocEvents = new ObservableCollection<string>();
```

This is neither a Dependency Property nor a property implementing INotifyPropertyChanged,it's also static, if you use a viewmodel you can do it  the way described below, well you may in codebehind to, but it invoke a double redraw. Anyways you need to change it to a DP or prop like below:

```
private ObservableCollection<string> ocEvents = new ObservableCollection<string>();
public ObservableCollection<string> OcEvents
{
    get { return ocEvents; }
    set
    {
        if (Equals(value, ocEvents)) return;
        ocEvents = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

[NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator] // Comment out if you don't have R#
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Binding to a static class/property has some weirdities to it, you have to bind differently. I'm off to bed now, so I can't provide and example. In the case above I would have created a vm, and a service for getting my event instead for making my vm unittestable (create an interface of the service providing events, and have the event property on the vm).

AddMsgToEvents()
Must be invoked on the dispatcher thread. A bad hack is to add the following code.  Call it with

```
    BeginInvoke(YourMethod);
```

Add the code to your vm's baseclass, I know the dispatcher should be "used" this way, but for simplicly.

```
    public void BeginInvoke(Action action)
    {
        if( Application.Current.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())                
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action);
        else
        {
            action();
        }
    }

    public void Invoke(Action action)
    {
        if (Application.Current.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action);
        else
        {
            action();
        }
    }


public static class PublicStaticFunctions
```

You sort of have your service right there, just unstatic it and create an interface of it :D Move your prop to vm/codebehind, or you need some changes to your binding there to, pluss hava a Prop or DP. short answer.

Edit: Example of service

```
public interface IEventService
{
    ObservableCollection<String> GetEvents();
    void AddEvent(String eventToAdd);
}

public  class EventService : IEventService
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<string> events;

    public EventService(ObservableCollection<string> events)
    {
        this.events = events;
    }

    public EventService()
    {
        events = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> Events
    {
        get { return events; }
        //set { events = value; }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<String> GetEvents()
    {
        return events;
    }

    public void AddEvent(String eventToAdd)
    {
        events.Add(eventToAdd);
    }
}
```

Feed this interface to your vm's ctor(TDD :) ) or codebehind ctor. Allocate and store it in a IOC cotainer, servicelocator or whatever.

Hope it helps,

Cheers,

Stian

Comment: ty for answer but i really need to bind to a static object :/

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG I avoid static if possible, and no you don't need a static binding. Make your thing(data provider class) there a non static service(with an interface) and either make a viewmodel and use it as a datacontext or use codebehind. Make your ocEvevents (should be OcEvents or just Events ;) )a proper with inot. or a vm or dp in codebehind. R# = Resharper

Comment: if i unstatic it how will i access it from different classes ?

Comment: If you have a look at frameworks such as galasoft mvvm light and DI or the ServiceLocator pattern (I find this to be an antipattern personally). You see one create services like you almost have done there, and create an interface. The interfaces are passed to the viewmodels constructors. That way you may find your data. But static bindings is possible, by forinstance use an instance or a direct binding. But I got to go to bed now. Hope I've helped you some.

Comment: thanks you helped however i cant find a working one with static :(

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG I'll provide you one in the morning, if no one else is awake. I use it rarely but you may inject it as a shared application resource App.Resources["yourkey"] as .. programatically or set it up as a shared resource in xaml you may bind to. Instancing is also possible as mentioned.

Comment: well i made it working with removing    <ListBox.ItemTemplate> and making this way binding ItemsSource="{x:Static local:PublicStaticFunctions.ocEventsCollection }" however how can i keep ItemTemplate :D